# Counting the times a single character is found in an entire SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, while-loop

If I have the following table in SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE #tv_shows
(
    tv_character varchar(50),
    show varchar(50),
    channel varchar(50)
 );

INSERT INTO #tv_shows (tv_character, show, channel)
SELECT 'Peter', 'Family Guy', 'Fox'
UNION ALL SELECT 'Ros|s', 'Friends', 'NBC|'
UNION ALL SELECT 'Britta', 'Community', 'N|BC'

select * from #tv_shows

tv_character  show        channel
Peter         Family Guy  Fox
Ros|s         Friends     NBC|
Britta        Community   N|BC
```

I'm looking for a method in SQL Server to "loop" through the `#tvshows` to count the number of times the `|` character is found in each column. The output I'm looking for is something along these lines:

```
tv_character  show  channel
1             0     2
```

**CLARIFICATION EDIT:** I want to apply the count-per-column in a looping fashion so that I don't have to code the function for each column. i.e., something that can be applied to the 3 column example here or applied to a 150 column data table.

Comment: Other than an academic/learning situation this seems to have little to no tangible benefit in the real world.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
select sum(len([character]) - len(replace([character], '|', ''))),
       sum(len(show) - len(replace(show, '|', ''))),
       sum(len(channel) - len(replace(channel, '|', '')))
from [data.table]
```

Comment: @bshelt141 . . . This answers the original question and was the first answer.  I think you should accept this answer and ask another regarding the dynamic query that you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this...

```
SELECT SUM(len(character) - len(replace(character, '|', ''))) AS character,
SUM(len(show) - len(replace(show, '|', ''))) AS show,
SUM(len(channel) - len(replace(channel, '|', ''))) AS channel
FROM data.table
```

Comment: I think this gets me most of the way there. Although I've edited the question to call it out further, the original question was asking for a looping type solution so that the user does not have to code for each explicit column. thanks.